# Punctuation for multiple independent clauses in the antecedent of a conditional sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

(1) If you like apples and your friends like bananas, you buy apples and bananas.

(2) If you like apples, and your friends like bananas, you buy apples and bananas.

Is (1) or (2) correct? I'm leaning toward (2) because "You like apples, and your friends like bananas" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer 1.  In (2) it seems that the phrase "and your friends like bananas" is parenthetical. But the phrase isn't parenthetical, it is necessary for the required sense.

Adding a comma doesn't seem to add much clarity, and may cause a slight problem. So I would apply the rule "if in doubt, leave it out".

That said, both are acceptable and neither contains a clear error of English.